# How to define import variable type

Tags: typescript

I have `noImplicitAny` set to `true` for my TypeScript compiler. When I use an import like the following, it throws an error because I am not explicitly defining a type for the `foo` variable:

`import * as foo from "bar";`

I am able to defined a type for `foo` using the CommonJS require syntax:

`const foo: FooType = require("bar");`

Is there a way to define a type for `foo` using the `import * as ...` syntax?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I believe you mean something like...

```
import * as foo: IFoo from "foo"
```

or

```
import foo : IFoo from "foo"
```

Is that accurate?

[This was discussed, but ultimately decided against.](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2709)

Instead, it was recommended that you `declare module 'bar'` and give it your appropriate typing. Once that's done you will be able to `import * as foo from "bar"` with proper typing.

[See this issue for more details on the recommended approach](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6615)

A potential example:

**untyped.d.ts**

```
declare module "bar" {
    const foo:IFoo;
    export = foo;
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...
    },
    "include": [
        "untyped.d.ts",
        "src/**/*.ts",
        "src/**/*.tsx"
    ]
}
```

the name "untyped.d.ts" has no real meaning here, I just personally use it as a catchall for the untyped modules in my personal projects. Feel free to name it whatever feels right to you.

p.s. you can also choose to use the `files` array property rather than `include` for this  but I tend to not bother because `files` doesn't respect the `exclude` property which is confusing to some folks. [See the docs for details.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Where do I put the module declaration? (the module I'm interested in adding type information for is a 3rd party dependency in `node_modules`)

Comment: @mattnedrich The simplest way is probably to create a `.d.ts` file in your project and add that file to the `includes` array of your `tsconfig.json`. You would write that declaration in that file.

Comment: Thanks! For completeness, can you please add an example of how the `.d.ts` file can be included from the `tsconfig.json` file?