# Dynamic return of a variable based on the argument

Tags: typescript

So I have n imports

```
import icon1 from './icons/icon1.svg';
import icon2 from './icons/icon2.svg';
// 100+ more imports
```

I want to write a function that returns correpsonding icon based on the icon name

```
export const getIcon: GetIcon = (iconName) => {
    switch (iconName) {
        case 'icon1': return icon1;
        case 'icon2': return icon2;
        // more returns
    }
 }
```

how do i do it without using switch case ?

In javascript I used to

```
export icon1 from './icons/icon1.svg';
export icon2 from './icons/icon2.svg';
// More icons
```

and in the second file

```
import * as icons from './icons';
export const getIcon = (iconName) => icons[iconName]
```

So I didn't have to write big switch statement to map the imports to the value. How can I simplify in typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given ES namespace import, you can get the typed keys `"icon1" | "icon1"` of the `icons`namespace:

```
import * as icons from './icons';

type IconKeys = keyof typeof icons;
```

Just restrict the `iconName` argument type of function `getIcon` to be one of the icon keys. Now `iconName` can be used as a computed property name to get the wanted icon.

```
export const getIcon = (iconName: IconKeys) => icons[iconName];

// or without explicit type
export const getIcon = (iconName: keyof typeof icons) => icons[iconName];
```

Comment: Thanks i added a validation check and everything worked as I expected
`const isValidIconName = (iconName: string): iconName is IconKeys => icons.hasOwnProperty(iconName);`

Answer (score 0):

In TS you can do very similar to JS.

1. In Icons file

   ```
   import icon1 from "./icon1";
   import icon2 from "./icon2";

   const icons = [icon1, icon2];  // type is string[]
   export = icons;
   ```
2. In second file

   ```
   import icons from './icons';

   export const getIcon = (icon: number) => icons[icon];   // type of getIcon is (icon: number): string
   ```

You can also look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42990843/7141073) with some addition details and ideas.

Comment: This is exactly like what I was doing since `icon` is string I need to put in map and export it but the issue is an issue as in js large number of imports and needs to copy-paste the same variables in a JSON object which I didn't have to do in JS world.